# elasticsearch jdbc river does not index all the documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using the elasticsearch jdbc river plugin, and I have a simple SQL table with 11 million rows. But when I use it to index the table, it stops somewhere at 2 million rows. On checking the elasticsearch log file, I did not find any errors. Does anyone know why that is happening?

Comment: +1, I have the same exact issue

Comment: After I upgraded to version 1.2 of elasticsearch and version 1.2.1 of the elasticsearch river jdbc plugin, the problem went away, I was able to index all of the rows.

Comment: I think that we all had the same issue with the river. I have posted a similar question a month ago and still didn't get an answer. The problem is related to the queue capacity. I think that the best thing to do is to open a issue about it in the plugin repo